# Failed to create sessionFactory in Hibernate ( How to save an object into an Oracle database using hibernate )

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate and am trying to code something. I'm getting an stuck with an error ( Failed to create sessionFactory object.java.lang.NullPointerException )

Some help will be much appreciated.

hibernate.cfg.xml file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
  ~
  ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
  ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
  -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orclpdb1</property>
    <property name="connection.username">oracle</property>
    <property name="connection.password">admin</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <mapping class="ProjectHib.dto.Client"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Client.hbm.xml file :

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name = "Client" table = "Client">

  <meta attribute = "class-description">
     This class contains the employee detail. 
  </meta>

  <id name = "ClientID" type = "int" column = "id">
     <generator class="native"/>
  </id>

  <property name = "name" column = "name" type = "string"/>
```

```
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And then the Client.java file :

```
package ProjectHib.dto;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Client {
@Id
private int ClientID;
private String name;


public Client() {}


public Client(int clientID, String name) {
    ClientID = clientID;
    this.name = name;
}


public int getClientID() {
    return ClientID;
}
public void setClientID(int clientID) {
    ClientID = clientID;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Finally, the Hibernate test file :

```
package ProjectHib.dto;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class TestHibernate {
    private static SessionFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
Client C1 = new Client();

    C1.setClientID(0);
    C1.setName("fat7i 1");

     try {
         factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      } catch (Throwable ex) { 
         System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
      }


    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(C1);
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    }
}
```

Edit : I was following a tutorial.. the purpose of this code is to save ( persist )  the object ( Clien C1 ) in a Oracle database ( I dont know if this clarifies things a bit )

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be useful to know what you're trying to achieve with this code. Please edit your post to include the codes purpose / objective.

Comment: Also please update your question title, so that it attracts the attention of the people who know how to solve your question - for example, "in Hibernate, how to move the blue box?"

Comment: Thanks for replying. I edited the post and I hope the clarification is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" as your 'connection.driver_class' instead of 'oracle.jdbc.driver'.
This only works for JDK-compliant versions of Java.